# Creating a relational database for Twitter

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm developing a Web app that revolves around the Twitter API. I'm a newbie and this is my first ever attempt at development so be gentle (please).

The problem I'm facing is: I have a table that contains the twitter user info: UserID(Unique) Name etc.. And another with specific tweets: TweetID(Unique) Text etc..

I want to be able specify if a particular UserID has Retweeted the tweet(using TweetId) already.

I don't care if he has retweeted outside my App, I just want to know if he did using my web app so I don't display it to him twice.

Comment: Make another table called `user_retweets` with the columns `UserID` and `TweetID`. When a user retweets, create an entry in the `user_retweets` table with that user's ID and the Tweet ID. To check if the user has retweeted _that_ tweet, do `SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN user_retweets ON Users.UserID = user_retweets.UserID WHERE user_retweets = ?` where `?` is the Tweet ID you're checking. A non-zero result set indicates that the user did retweet a tweet.

Comment: Also **why** is this migrated from `dba`... it walks like a database question and quacks like a database question, but it definitely is too broad. Should've been closed as such originally.